# Is this serial downvoting?

Tags: support, voting

From yesterday, I am having frequent downvotes, without any kind of comments. I have received 5 down votes since last night. This never happened since I have been here for 10 months. And the posts which have got down votes are quite old.

Is this serial downvoting by one person? Can this lead me to Answer ban? Or why did not voting detection script detect this?

Comment: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: "Serial voting is explained as a succession of votes cast by one user toward another witin a short span of time." That is not happening in your case as the down votes are spread out over a long period (4 in 24 hours).

Comment: Then @DavidPostill it is normal downvoting? Or same person took a long time to cast each individual downvotes (So that he remains undetected).

Comment: Moderators cannot tell who cast votes.

Comment: OK @DavidPostill if this continues to occur then what should I do?

Comment: [What should you do if you're serial downvoted & it isn't automatically reversed within 24 hours? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212332/what-should-you-do-if-youre-serial-downvoted-it-isnt-automatically-reversed/212339#212339)